# Testing using jest and sqlite was blocked

Tags: sqlite, jestjs, knex.js

I wrote some test cases:

```
describe('test function', () => {
  beforeEach(() => knex('test').truncate())

  describe('test case', () => {
    it('test case', async () => {
        // some code
    })
  })

})
```

When I run a test using `jest` it try to run my sqlite file but with -journal and I get this error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\testProject\dbTest.sqlite-journal'
```

when i delete `knex('test').truncate()` everything working fine

i need to use it to delete all data from test table to add another data for each test case

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

i disabled the `journal_mode` before `truncate` everything working fine

```
beforeEach(async () => {
      await knex.raw('PRAGMA journal_mode = "OFF"');
      await knex('test').truncate();
  });
```

Comment: Right you were using sqlite... if you set journal mode off you won't be able to rollback transactions anymore :( I haven't used sqlite in ages so I don't know if destroy / init works with that to kill connections.

Comment: Really glad I found this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy knex after test is finished or otherwise there will be left open connections in pool which prevents node from stopping.

```
after(async () => await knex.destroy())
```

Also would be good to wait that truncate finish in `beforeEach()`

```
beforeEach(async () => await knex('test').truncate())
```

Comment: when i add knex.destroy() i got another error "Unable to acquire a connection"

Comment: check your logs if you are actually trying to make new queries after destroy() call... or actually after destroy() you could init knex again with calling `knex.initialize()` again. That will re-create pool and there should not be any connection open anymore.

Comment: when i try to use `knex.initialize()` i got an error `client.initialize is not a function`

Comment: Thats strange, since there is an integration test for it https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/e971c5198b8d33d375030e8b03ae13d2730ab04a/test/integration/suite.js#L48 and knex.initialize should call client.initializePool and not client.initialize https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/9aa7085b052938dc5252d10b2b418a475637eda5/lib/util/make-knex.js#L63